# Is this conditional sum function valid for linear programming?

Tags: functions, optimization, linear-programming

Linear programming requires a linear function to maximize in order to operate properly.

I am trying to figure out whether I could use linear programming to solve a problem. However, I would need a function that looks like the following.

Consider three non-negative integer variables $x1$, $x2$ and $x3$. The maximization function $f$ is defined as following:

```
f(x1,x2,x3) = (x1+x2+x3) if (x1+x2+x3) < 10
            = 0 otherwise
```

Is there any theoretical objection to using such a maximization function in linear programming?

Comment: Is there any reason not to make the (x1+x2+x3) < 10 a constraint and keep the maximization function simply as f(x1,x2,x3) = (x1+x2+x3)? I otherwise see no problem, although more constraints on x1, x2, and x3 would be needed to make linear programming effective.

Comment: Ohhh, nice idea. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NK1406 provides a nice workaround:

```
 Make (x1+x2+x3) < 10 a constraint
 and keep the maximization function simply as f(x1,x2,x3) = (x1+x2+x3)
```